# Selecting columns messes up order of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables `blog_articles`, `blog_tags` and `blog_articles_tags`. Pretty basic stuff, a blog where articles can have tags.

```
CREATE TABLE `blog_articles` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `author` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `author` (`author`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`body`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `blog_articles_tags` (
  `article` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article`,`tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `blog_tags` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is a working example, selecting blog posts with their tags and author

[image]

But if I switch the sort from descending to ascending, I get messed up results

[image]

However if I remove the columns of the `blog_tags` table from the list of columns to select, the order is correct

[image]

There are two questions I would like to ask:

1. Why is the sequence of the rows altered by the columns that are selected?
2. How can I prevent this without modifying the SQL statement anywhere outside of the inner-most query?

I cannot modify the SQL statement because that is an automatically generated statement and I can not determine (easily if at all) what the sort will be and if any successive columns added to the select clause will alter the results even further.

Comment: SQL tables and results sets represent *unordered* sets. The only exception is when you have an `ORDER BY` in the outermost part of the query.  You have no such `ORDER BY`, so you should have no expectation on the final ordering of the result set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have a sort on the inner-most query, I was expecting joins to respect this, as they do except in the case I'm having trouble with?

Comment: In MSSQL I think your inner `ORDER BY` is invalid syntax entirely.  If mysql is allowing it, it is either being ignored or adding unneeded overhead to your performance.  Once it becomes a derived table, it's fair game to have the engine return the outer query any way it sees fit, given the absence of that outer query's own `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @php_nub_qq An `ORDER BY` on a sub-query makes absolutely no difference on the final sorting of the outer query, other than if you were also performing a `LIMIT` to limit the results from the sub-query

Comment: @MikeBrant this is the only reason I have an inner query, I will inevitably need to paginate the results AFAIK this is the only way to perform pagination with joins.

Comment: SQL Server only allows ORDER BY in subqueries that return a fixed number of rows (a  la TOP).

Comment: @php_nub_qq That is fine. You can use ORDER BY and LIMIT in the subquery in this fashion, however you should understand that this still will not provide any ordering in the outer query.  If you want to provide ordering on the outer query, you would need an additional ORDER BY in the outer query,

Answer (score 0):

Queries in SQL are unordered unless you specify an `ORDER BY`. Any ordering you happen to get is an artifact of the implementation and cannot be relied upon.

You have an `ORDER BY` in one of your virtual tables, but nothing for the outer query.  Since it includes several joins you can't even count on MySQL coincidentally preserving the order of the virtual table.

There's little reason to put an `ORDER BY` on a sub-query unless you're doing something advanced like adding a row-number.  So the whole sub-query can be dropped and just join on `blog_articles`.  Then you can `ORDER BY blog_articles.id`.

Comment: The sub-query is there because I am limiting the results, if I drop it the limit will not work properly.

Comment: @php_nub_qq I see no limit on the sub-query, but maybe you'll add it later. You can keep the sub-query if you like, but `ORDER BY` belongs on the outer query.